# compare string from a list of strings

Tags: c#

i'm reading a file with 10002 lines, in each line there is a name that I want to compare with a single string, and if this string is the same, i want to add the string file to a listbox, I'm using the FILE.READLINE and then add each line to a list then I use .CONTAINS method and doesnt works also with == but that doesn work either...Any suggestions?

```
//This is my code:

foreach (string h in Directory.EnumerateFiles(NomDirec, "resume*"))
{
  this.listBox1.Items.Add(h);
  //Read Lines here and add them to a list and a listbox 
  var NombreLinea = File.ReadLines(h);
  foreach (var item in NombreLinea)
  {
    NombreAbuscar.Add(item).Remove(item.IndexOf(":"));
    this.listBox3.Items.Add(item);
  }

  //Here I want to add this file only if "NombreCompleto" is present in my resume file.
  foreach (string t in Directory.EnumerateFiles(NomDirec, "ESSD1*"))
  {
    string[] Nombre = File.ReadLines(t).ElementAtOrDefault(6).Split(':');
    string[] ApellidoPat = File.ReadLines(t).ElementAtOrDefault(7).Split(':');
    string[] ApellidoMat = File.ReadLines(t).ElementAtOrDefault(8).Split(':');
    string NombreCompleto = ApellidoPat[1] + ApellidoMat[1] + "," + " " + Nombre[1] + " " + ":";
    foreach (var item in NombreAbuscar)
    {
      if (NombreCompleto == item)
      {
        this.listBox1.Items.Add(t);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Could be a way to only read the a certain part of the line and add it to my listbox??

Comment: If you place a breakpoint on `NombreCompleto == item`, do you ever see anything similar come across that it's skipping?  If you were to use `NombreCompleto.Equals(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`, does that work?

Comment: the thing is that each line of my resume file contains 5 columns, name:,age,height,weight,adress.
and NombreCompleto is exactly the same as name:, I only want to compare the first colum of names and if this is true add the ESSD file to the listbox...

Comment: So, when we get to the comparison at the end, what is "item"?  A name?

Comment: I edited to only add to my list the name of the resume file, but still doesnt add it to my listbox, and NombreCompleto is exactly the same as the name that I adding to my list, I dont know what's happening...:(